# Do long term operation only once per NUnit test run

Tags: c#, nunit

what I try to do is make a long term operation only once per all Unit tests.

OneTimeSetup is not the soltution I'm searching for :).

I want to do this:

1. Before starting the first test do a long time operation for example load a large file.
2. Start TestFixture 1

   - Run Test 1 (Result of step 1 must be available)
   - Run Test 2 (Result of step 1 must be available)
3. Start TestFixture 2

   - Run Test 1 (Result of step 1 must be available)
   - Run Test 2 (Result of step 1 must be available)
4. ... and so on
5. Cleanup

Is this possible?

Any suggestions

Greetings Michael

Comment: What you are describing is OneTimeSetup, did you use it correctly? Can you provide some code to show us how you did things and what you want to achieve?

Comment: No this is not OneTimeSetup. In my understanding OneTimeSetup is called once per TestFixture.

Comment: @MichaelInsberg You have missed a different use of OneTmeSetUp. Look up SetUpFixture in the docs.

Comment: SetUpFixture is the solution for one namespace. But I have tests in different namespaces that should use the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate class with a static constructor:

```
public static class LongTimeOperation
{
    static LongTimeOperation()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Resource = (++count).ToString();
    }

    public static string Resource { get; set; }
    private static int count = 0;
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture1
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        resource = LongTimeOperation.Resource;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1() => Assert.That(resource, Is.EqualTo("1"));

    [Test]
    public void Test2() => Assert.That(resource, Is.EqualTo("1"));

    private string resource;
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture2
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        resource = LongTimeOperation.Resource;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1() => Assert.That(resource, Is.EqualTo("1"));

    [Test]
    public void Test2() => Assert.That(resource, Is.EqualTo("1"));

    private string resource;
}
```

Comment: This was also my first idea. But it don't works. I use a static class outside the unit test. But in every "TestFixture run" the static class was new instanciated.

Comment: Using the NUnit3TestAdapter inside VisualStudio the static constructor is invoked only once if I select both TestFixtures (or select the test project containing both TestFixtures) and then execute Run (this is also asserted inside the tests). Also verified it with the debugger.

Comment: You are right but only if the test are in the same assembly.
I habe one base test in one assembly an another test using the same static object in another assembly. Then the constructor is called twice.

Comment: When using `NUNIT3-CONSOLE` you could try the option `--domain=DOMAIN`, then all tests should be executed within the same AppDomain and thus static members should be initialized only once.  Currently there seems to be no similar option when using the VSTestAdapter.